# In Django, getting next/previous object by date when some share the same date

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django I have a `Letter` model:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    letter_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
```

When viewing an individual letter, using a `DateDetailView()`, I want to show "next" and "previous" links. To get the next/previous `Letter` I can do this in one of the view's methods (and similar to get `next_letter`):

```
try:
    previous_letter = self.model.objects.filter(
                    letter_date__lt=date).order_by('-letter_date')[:1].get()
except self.model.DoesNotExist:
    previous_letter = None
```

That works fine if there's only one `Letter` per day, but some days have multiple letters, and this code will skip subsequent letters on the same day.

How can I ensure next/previous doesn't skip letters? This doesn't sound hard, but my brain is struggling...

**EDIT:** In case it helps here's a list of some of the `Letter`s dates and their `pk`s:

- 13325 1665-12-13
- 13326 1666-01-31
- 13327 1666-02-17
- 13328 1666-02-17
- 13329 1666-02-18

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a second argument to `order_by`. While also adding a second argument to the `filter` method. This way, Django will return a list of objects with dates less than `date` and order them first by their `letter_date` field and then by their `primary key`.

```
previous_letter = self.model.objects.filter(
                letter_date__lt=date, pk__gt=pk).order_by('-letter_date', 'pk')
```

Comment: Thanks... but that doesn't return anything for me. Doesn't it assume that `letter_date` and `pk` share similar ordering? These `Letter`s could be added to the database in any order so that's not necessarily true.

Comment: (To clarify, they're letters written in the 17th century, so they're not added as they're written, or anything like that.)

Comment: i understand that the pk is not similar ordering it does not matter. It just example, i want to say you need double field order by, to get the same letter sequence, each time. So if you add my example you need start paginate again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "you need start paginate again".

Comment: i mean, you need open page with the first letter.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few things...

I think the only/best way is to add another field to `Letter`, used as a secondary field when ordering, so that Letters from the same day are always in the same order:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    letter_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['letter_date', 'order',]
```

Then in the view we have to look for either an earlier `Letter` from the same day *or* a `Letter` from an earlier day. Here's my full view, in case it's useful to anyone:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic.dates import DateDetailView

from letters.models import Letter


class LetterDetailView(DateDetailView):
    model = Letter
    date_field = 'letter_date'
    year_format = '%Y'
    month_format = '%m'
    day_format = '%d'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LetterDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        extra_context = self.get_next_previous()
        context.update(extra_context)
        return context

    def get_next_previous(self):
        date = self.model.letter_date
        order = self.model.order

        try:
            previous_letter = self.model.objects \
                                .filter( \
                                    Q(letter_date__lte=date, order__lt=order) \
                                    | \
                                    Q(letter_date__lt=date) \
                                ) \
                                .order_by('-letter_date', '-order')[:1] \
                                .get()
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            previous_letter = None

        try:
            next_letter = self.model.objects \
                                .filter( \
                                    Q(letter_date__gte=date, order__gt=order) \
                                    | \
                                    Q(letter_date__gt=date) \
                                ) \
                                .order_by('letter_date', 'order')[:1] \
                                .get()
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            next_letter = None

        return {
            'previous_letter': previous_letter,
            'next_letter': next_letter,
        }
```

I didn't want to add another field but I think it's the only way to keep lists and next/previous links consistent.